# react SWR does not set loading to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, swr

I don't know why my `bagList` get populated, but loading wont stop to run. I use SWR to fetch data, and console log will print:

```
loading undefined
error undefined
bagLength undefined
bagList (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]"
```

So, the loading it's never set to false, and i won't be able to show the data.

```
 const { data: bagList, error, mutate: mutateBags, bagLength, loading }
 = useSWR(AREAS_URL, getTodos(id, currentCatId));

return(
loading ? ( <CardSkeleton />
  ) : (
    <Box>{bagList?.map((element, i) =>() }</Box>
)
```

It may not look like enough code, but the error it's between those lines.
I copy the SWR syntax from this https://github.com/gitdagray/react-swr/blob/main/react-swr-completed/src/features/todos/TodoList.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Because `useSWR` hook returns `isLoading` not `loading`. That's why you have undefined

Comment: Yes it looks like useSWR only takes isLoading

Comment: ok now I get "loading false", but data is not showed on component

Comment: bagList have objects inside, but nothing inside `Box`? Do you have any errors in console?